# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power while plotting poisson distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime

I want to run this piece of code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import factorial

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

x_plot = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, parameters), 'r-', lw=2) 
plt.show()
```

in which `parameters = 0.00213553`

But every time this warning occurs:

```
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
 return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)
```

and just a horizontal line appears.

I've checked similar problems but they didn't really help.
I've also tried to cast the function return value to `float128` which didn't work either.
(using `Python 2.7.6 64-bit`)

Comment: Guessing blindly as no definition of factorial() is provided and the code misses import statements, the indents are wrong  etc. but trusting the error, I would try to look at the partial results, candidates for the hinted power might be the argument of the `**` operator or the `-lamb` argument in np.exp() ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know which `factorial` you are using. But when I use `math.factorial`, the code cannot even work. Then I tried with the `scipy.misc.factorial`, which can really take `numpy array` as an input. And when I run the following, it give me no error or warning.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc

parameters = 0.00213553

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/scipy.misc.factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

x_plot = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, parameters), 'r-', lw=2) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i edited my question and add full code. yes i used factorial in scipy.misc but it doesn't show the right graph.@MaThMax

Comment: @Shi.Bi, can you try to break your line into different parts, like (lamb**k`, `scipy.misc.factorial(k)` , `np.exp(-lamb)`, see which part is actually causing the problem? And if it is just a `RuntimeWarning` but not error, why can't you see the correct graph? Can you show the full list of `Warnings` you see?

Comment: i finally figure it out. thankyou :) i had to tune plt.xlim and plt.ylim to see the result. @ MaThMaX